# Can you have inner php tags within variable output?

Tags: php, jquery, html

Can you use inner php tags within php variable output? Any hints would be great. Thank you.

Code is below

```
    <div class="slick-carousel">
      <div><a 
          <?php if(!empty($pp_image_lightbox_title)) { ?>
              data-title="
              <?php if(!empty($image_desc)) { ?>
                  <?php echo htmlentities($image_desc); ?>
              <?php } ?>"<?php } ?> 
              class="fancy-gallery" data-fancybox-group="fancybox-thumb" href="
              <?php echo $image_url[0]; ?>
              "><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/shutterstock_45145123.jpg" alt="" class="portfolio_img"/>
      </a></div>
      <div><img src="img/lutron_lg.png" alt="Lutron" /></div>
      <div><img src="img/savant_lg.png" alt="Savant" /></div>
      <div><img src="img/elan_lg.png" alt="Elan" /></div>
      <div><img src="img/crestron_lg.png" alt="Crestron" /></div>
      <div><img src="img/rti_lg.png" alt="RTI" /></div>       
      <div><img src="img/cedia_lg.png" alt="Cedia" /></div>
      <div><img src="img/industry_partner_lg.png" alt="Industry Partner" /></div>
      <div><img src="img/amx_lg.png" alt="AMX Inconcert" /></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: just concatenate using . (period) http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 1):

if you need to put some other PHP variables inside you can just do something like that :

```
$image_content = 'bla bla bla bla'. $your_other_stuff .'bla bla bla';
```

In case you need to put something else at the end of your output you can do :

```
$image_content = '<div class="slick-carousel">
  <div><a <?php if(!empty($pp_image_lightbox_title)) { ?>data-title="<?php if(!empty($image_desc)) { ?><?php echo htmlentities($image_desc); ?><?php } ?>"<?php } ?> class="fancy-gallery" data-fancybox-group="fancybox-thumb" href="<?php echo $image_url[0]; ?>"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/shutterstock_45145123.jpg" alt="" class="portfolio_img"/></a></div>
  <div><img src="img/lutron_lg.png" alt="Lutron" /></div>
  <div><img src="img/savant_lg.png" alt="Savant" /></div>
  <div><img src="img/elan_lg.png" alt="Elan" /></div> ';

$content_at_the_end = ' bla bla bla bla ';

$image_content .= $content_at_the_end;
```

And if what you need is to actually replace something like alt="Lutron" you can use a native php function to do that :

```
$image_content = '<div class="slick-carousel">
  <div><a <?php if(!empty($pp_image_lightbox_title)) { ?>data-title="<?php if(!empty($image_desc)) { ?><?php echo htmlentities($image_desc); ?><?php } ?>"<?php } ?> class="fancy-gallery" data-fancybox-group="fancybox-thumb" href="<?php echo $image_url[0]; ?>"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/shutterstock_45145123.jpg" alt="" class="portfolio_img"/></a></div>
  <div><img src="img/lutron_lg.png" alt="Lutron" /></div>
  <div><img src="img/savant_lg.png" alt="Savant" /></div>
  <div><img src="img/elan_lg.png" alt="Elan" /></div>
  <div><img src="img/crestron_lg.png" alt="Crestron" /></div>
  <div><img src="img/rti_lg.png" alt="RTI" /></div>       
  <div><img src="img/cedia_lg.png" alt="Cedia" /></div>
  <div><img src="img/industry_partner_lg.png" alt="Industry Partner" /></div>
  <div><img src="img/amx_lg.png" alt="AMX Inconcert" /></div>
</div> ';

$new_content = ' alt="new_alt" ';
$image_content = str_replace( 'alt="Lutron"', $new_content, $image_content);
```

It is going to replace the alt="Lutron" by alt="new_alt" into your $image_content variable.

Comment: Wow! This is a great help. Thank you Alex :)